# How to access a specific child div using xpath? (Selenium Java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class = "heading">
        <span class="wName">Name</span>
        <div class="foo1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="foo2" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already located element panel and I'm trying to test when foo2 doesn't appear with the following line of code:

```
if (panel.findElement(By.xpath("../div[@class='foo2']")).getCssValue("display").equals("none"))
```

I'm not sure why this won't retrieve the element properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is wrong! `..` means "parent of". Single dot `.` would mean relative to current location.

Try: `panel.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='foo2']")`

Comment: alternatively, you can use the cleaner CSS solution. @OP.  `By.cssSelector("div.foo2")`

Comment: @sircapsalot If we are going after "clean", then I think `By.className("foo2")` wins out.

Comment: or of course we can go the "less clean" route.   `By.cssSelector("div[class~='panel']>div[class~='heading']>div[class]:nth-child(3)")` `;)`

Comment: Actually, since the div of interest isn't a direct child of the panel, the XPath needs to be `.//div[@class='foo2']`, or `./div/div[@class='foo2']`, or `./*/div[@class='foo2']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use descendant

```
panel.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel']/descendant::div[@class='foo2']"));
```

Source http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/xpath.xtp#descendant